# Can you find a lock grinder during the "Quell the Bandit Threat" mission?

Tags: rage

So I've recently started playing Rage, and during the "Quell the Bandit Threat" mission, I noticed the following locked door inside the bandits' hideout:

[image: Locked door]

As the prompt kindly informs me, I'll need a lock grinder to open that door. However, after clearing out all the bandits and looting everything I could find, I did not come across a lock grinder.

Is there one well hidden on the premises, or will I have to return to this door later if I want to find out what lies behind it?

Comment: I am pretty sure the lock grinder is crafted. So it can't found anywhere. I don't have any information beyond that though, so no solution from me. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

From all my searching, I never found one, or the parts to make one. You will be able to return later for a follow up mission, Missing Person, which you find on the job board in Wellspring.

You can also return to the Ghost Hideout while roaming freely. I just tested and got in the door.

Comment: Correct, I did the same today.

Answer (score 0):

I did find one once.  I think I was battling mutants in that specific mission. or gearheads. or both.

edit: I think it was during the distillery mission, not sure.

its one of the later ones.  plan on crafting them yourself if you expect you might need ammo in the middle of fights.  (there's some other cool stuff to be found in the rooms also ;) )